# MySQL: Auto Increment for updates

Tags: mysql, key, auto-increment, sql-insert, insert-update

While inserting a new row, the auto-increment `id` gets a new value (previous + 1) for that row. How can I make mysql to `auto-increment` in the case of updates also?

Suppose, the last inserted row has an id = 10. If I insert a row, it's `id` will be `11`. How can I update the id of the 7th row to `12` If I throw an update command?

I tried the following which did update the id = `12` but the `auto_increment` was still left to `11` and it caused a `Duplicate key '11' Exception` for an insert after the update command was run.

```
update `users` set id = LAST_INSERT_ID()+1  where cid = "c1" and uid = "p1"
```

How can I make auto-increment to increment even for `updates` or `insert .. on duplicate key update` ?

Comment: Just add a timestamp column named `updatedAt` which gives you the order you need, right?

Comment: @juergend I thought about it. The issue with using a timestamp is that I need every record to have a unique timestamp and an index(just like id) because I have to query the DB on the basis of timestamp. eg: fetch 100 rows up or down a particular timestamp for a certain cid & uid. Any workaround for that?

Comment: I can use fractional timestamp up to micro-second but for the rows inserted in a single query, even that timestamp comes out to be the same. And above that, is using an index on that a good idea, apart from other required indexes which I already have?(though I would be using an extra index in case of id also but with fractional time stamp, the index size would be greater)